# how to Validate double values with regular expression in jsf?

Tags: jsf

it should allow upto 30 digits before decimal and atleast 1 , atmost 2 digits after decimal

Comment: I'm not familiar with jsf, but if you have the value as a string, the regex should look like this: ^[0-9]{1,30}\.[0-9]{0,2}$

Comment: Yes esel is right ..

for javascript validation it's an right answer for more regex visit http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Answer (score 5):

If you use JSF 2.0 you can use the regex-validator tag:

```
<h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{user.password}">
  <f:validateRegex pattern="add your pattern here" />
</h:inputSecret>
```

If you are still on JSF 1.x I think you have to write your own custom validator by creating a class that implements `javax.faces.validator.Validator` interface. [Here is a good tutorial how to achieve this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jsf-validation-tutorial-error).

Answer (score 2):

Here in this example is the solution i suggest for validating double:

```
<h:inputText id="someField" value="#{yourBean.doubleValue}">
    <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2" />
    <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="1" maximum="30"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Use the attributes of the convertNumber tag to set the limits you need.